# RTL (right-to-left) comment text in Word 365

Tags: mac, office-365, macos

I'm running Mac OS 14.0. In both Word 365 on a Mac (Microsoft Office 365 for Mac version 16.80) and the web version, I can't get RTL (right-to-left) text to appear in comments. This type of text is used in Hebrew and Arabic, for example.

In both cases, there's no problem with RTL text in the body of the document. But when it comes to the little comment bubbles that appear on the right side of a Word document, the formatting options are limited.

For example, on Word for Mac if you highlight the text within a comment and right-click it, there aren't any formatting options. The web version, by contrast, does show formatting options when you right click, but they don't work for me. I can select Text Direction > Right-to-Left, but then nothing happens to the text in the comment bubble.

This is a real problem for collaborating with others using Word for Windows, where apparently this is not a problem.

Comment: @TomGewecke done

Comment: In my Ventura and Word 16.78, I do have rtl/ltr writing direction options for both paragraph and selection when I control click on the comment field.

Comment: @TomGewecke I tried many times and do not see what you are describing. Perhaps there is some setting I'm missing. Can you post as an answer and make a screen recording so I can see what you are doing? What settings might I have wrong? I have Arabic and English as the languages, by the way, and of course the whole point is with Arabic since it is RTL

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if Sonoma broke this, but I am able to choose comment text direction in my Word 16.80 in Ventura with Control Click.

[image]